# Why do my grid elements have so big "gap" between them, while grid-gap=0?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am currently trying to realize my stream overlay using HTML\CSS\JS.

I am stuck at web-camera scene. For some reason, text below camera showing with a big gap above it, but for all my knowledge I don't have any gaps determined.

Why is this and what do I do?

Noticed, that this isn't happening in these code snippets. Probably, it is because they are too small. Anyways, there are screenshots.

[screenshot before adding text div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGo5M.png)

[and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIcVR.png)

```css
* {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.webcam-container {
  margin-left: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
}

.webcam {
  border: 10px solid white;
  /*    background-color: white;*/
  height: 540px;
  width: 960px;
}

.chat {
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.chat div {
  height: 800px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="webcamScreen.css">
  <title>Web-camera screen</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="webcam-container">
      <div class="webcam">Web-camera</div>
      <div style="align-self: flex-start">dfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdffsd</div>
    </div>

    <div class="chat">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I do not see a gap.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I included the screenshots of the problem. Don't really know why snippets do not show this gap

Comment: Because you are using `display: grid` on the container  and `.webcam { height: 540px; }` . In bigger screen, `webcam` cannot fill all the space of container so we see some space in-between added by container. Try adding following css   `.webcam { align-self: end; }`

Comment: If you need more than just close the gap between webcam and text, maybe you should check out grid css properties and try different layout. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @SyTran Thank you! I used `align-self: center` and it worked perfectly for me! ♥

Comment: @SyTran but.. why does now text in div under .webcam-container div goes through the borders of .webcam-container? [screenshot](https://sun9-30.userapi.com/c857720/v857720671/21d5bf/Xpf1T_ryi0U.jpg)

Comment: That's how grid works, so it can keep the children size's ratios on different screen size. Instead of setting fixed size for webcam, you should also apply the grid layout on inner elements to keep it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
.webcam-container {
  margin-left: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
}
```

Here you reassigned `display` to `grid` on the last ling. So both child blocks starts to act like grid row blocks with auto height. `display: grid` requires little more settings. Here is the code which will help you to get rid of extra gap.

```
.webcam-container {
    margin-left: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* it means we have only one column */
    grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr; /* the first row height is auto and the second is all the height left */ 
}
```

More about [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).

Comment: Yeap, it fixes this, but how do I now center these blocks horizontally?

Comment: Hard to say. I would rewrite the code a bit if I were you. Depends on desired result, minimum and maximum or video block, its proportions and general responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjust height or padding to position webcam as your desire.

```css
.webcam {
    border: 10px solid white;
    /* background-color: white; */
    /* height: 540px; */
    /* width: 960px; */
    height: 80%;
    grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

[image: The result]